# Android : How to twist an image?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I had asked a similar question earlier but received no conclusive answers. I want to twist an image starting from one end. How do I achieve it ? The context is android canvas and the image is a bitmap. if i have to convert it into a byte array can someone please post the code for conversion to byte array and pixel sampling in order to twist the bitmap?
Thanks in advance
Sameer Raina

Comment: what do you mean by twist? can you show some image what you want to achieve? What you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly, [crop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29) is what you are looking for:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOriginal, x, y, width, height, matrix, true);
```

`x` and `y` are coordinates in the original image, `width` and `height` - dimension.